# Story identification: A book with three sci-fi short stories

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much, but I recall reading a book with three short sci-fi stories like 20 years ago from my old school library.

I just remember that one of the stories took place on the moon or some asteroid and the main character had some kind of encounter with some kind of ghosts/clones. Maybe another of the stories had something to do with Jupiter, but I am not sure at all. The title could be something like "Title of the first story" + "And another two stories", but not sure either.

Sorry not having more details but it is being a long time and I just wanted to try here if there was any luck.

Comment: Ghosts/clones. Wow.

Comment: This isn't enough for an answer, but Jupiter + clones sounds a tiny bit like either Simak's "Desertion" or Anderson's "Call Me Joe".  I can't find evidence that either of them were ever in a book with exactly three stories, though.

Comment: see OP comment below indicating likely duplicate status

Answer (score 7):

[The Gods Themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves) by Isaac Asimov?

The book has three seemingly unrelated stories that turn out to be closely related to each other.

The second story is set in a parallel universe where matter is able to pass through other matter, so some of the creatures are ghost-like.

The third story is set on the moon. While it doesn't involve clones, it does involve genetic engineering.

Even if it isn't the book you are thinking of it, go read it! It is a great book. Dr A wrote that it was his favourite novel. His very last story, "Gold" references the second story.

Comment: It looks that it could be this one. I am going to read it anyway, so thank you

Comment: The three stories, or rather parts of the book are called "Against Stupidity...", "...The Gods Themselves...", and "...Contend In Vain?"

Comment: @Jucamola If it was that one, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a shot in the dark, but maybe *The New Atlantis and Other Novellas of Science Fiction*?  My limited evidence:
1) It does have exactly three stories
2) It is titled "story name and other stories"
3) The first story, Gene Wolfe's "Silhouette", does have to do with a ghost-like figure
4) It was published in 1975, so it's old enough to have been read "20 years ago"